# iPhone Photo/Pattern Recognition

Tags: iphone, pattern-recognition, image-recognition

Does anyone know of a good starting point to look into pattern and/or photo recognition development for the iPhone? In searching for it, I can only find examples of existing applications, but I would like to start developing one myself.

Comment: I'd start by just looking up pattern/photo recognition, if you are familiar with Objective C, it shouldn't be too hard to transcode the algorithm. If you are starting both from scratch, then I'd think that's pretty ambitious unless you are a really seasoned developer. Start smaller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O'Reilly came out with a [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516130) about the [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) project recently.

> OpenCV is a computer vision library originally developed by Intel. It is free for use under the open source BSD license. The library is cross-platform. It focuses mainly on real-time image processing, as such, if it finds Intel's Integrated Performance Primitives on the system, it will use these commercial optimized routines to accelerate itself.

It is all in C but that should be no problem to call from Objective-C. There are also iPhone port of the OpenCV library available.